# placing 3 divs under 3 divs

Tags: html, css

I have a countdown (made with js,but for this example i will have 3 numbers) and i want to structure it like this:

23   55   12

h    m    s

How can i do this?I saw in other posts that many of people use `position:relative` and `position:absolute`, but i don't think this is the best solution.

My html code:

```html
<div class="offer-countdown">
  <div class="ct-background">
    <div class="ct-background-element">
      23
    </div>
    <div>hours</div>
    <div class="ct-background-element">
      55
    </div>
    <div>minutes</div>
    <div class="ct-background-element">
      12
    </div>
    <div>seconds</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What's the point to explain what i tried to do?
I tried to  "code this by miself" and it didn't worked out.You want to have a version 1 css,version 2 css and a version 3 css to see what i did wrong?

Comment: Here is some basics on [`HTML div tags`](https://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_div_tag.cfm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it with the ***Flexbox***:

```css
.ct-background {
  display: flex;
}

.ct-background-element {
  display: flex; /* displays flex-items (children) inline by default */
  flex-direction: column; /* stacks them vertically */
  align-items: center; /* makes them horizontally centered */
  margin: 0 5px; /* e.g. */
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-countdown">
  <div class="ct-background">
    <div class="ct-background-element">23 <span>h</span></div>
    <div class="ct-background-element">55 <span>m</span></div>  
    <div class="ct-background-element">12 <span>s</span></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice...Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that we should use the right tool for the right problem. If you need a grid-like layout, you need [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). Using a list of flexbox doesn't make sense, in my opinion.

```css
.ct-background {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="offer-countdown">
  <div class="ct-background">
    <div class="ct-background-element">
      23
    </div>
    <div>hours</div>
    <div class="ct-background-element">
      55
    </div>
    <div>minutes</div>
    <div class="ct-background-element">
      12
    </div>
    <div>seconds</div>
  </div>
```